# Why fabric can connect to remote host immediately while normal connecting needs to wait 20 seconds?

Tags: ssh, python

I'm using a remote hosting service. Everytime I connect to it.

It costs me 20 seconds or more to wait for the password input line prompt out.

But today I used python fabric module.

I set the host name and password in the env configuration.

And within a second it connects to the remote host and execute the command.

What happened here?

Comment: Asked in just 22 sec and all of sudden answer appears. Really quick .... it seems like you are answering your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe GSSAPIAuthentication and reverse DNS resolution are the two usual culprits for this.  As Fabric is responding quickly, it suggests that reverse DNS resolution isn't enabled on the server.

What happens if you use:-

```
ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no <username@host>
```

If that improves things, then it can be made permanent for you by adding`GSSAPIAuthentication no` to `~/.ssh/ssh_config`.  Or, it can be made permanent by adding the same to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on your server (path may be slightly different).

GSS-API is used in Single Sign On scenarios.  For example, using a Kerberos server for managing your users. A remote hosting service will most probably not be providing this type of service, so GSS-API is not relevant to you in this case and can therefore be disabled.

If you connect with a few `-v` options you should see the client and server attempting (unsuccessfully) to negotiate GSS:-

```
ssh -vvv <username@host>
```

You can disable this on a host by host basis by adding the `Host` keyword to your `ssh_config` file:-

```
Host my_remote_hosting_server_hostname
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

See the man page for ssh_config for more details.

Comment: I used that, and exactly as you said, and I can connect to the remote host immediately, magic!

Comment: What's this GSSAPI here, was it useful or essential?

Comment: yes. it shows 'debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available'